# Gradle execute task after test phase even if test has failed

Tags: java, testing, build, gradle

I am using gradle as my builder. After running all of my test I want to execute additional task. If there are no test failures

```
test.doLast { /*my task*/ }
```

works fine. But if there is at least one test failure my task does not execute.

Is there a way to execute my task even if some of my test failed.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`test.doLast` doesn't add a new task, but adds another *task action* to the `test` task. What you can do instead is to declare a *finalizer task*:

```
task foo(type: ...) { ... } // regular task declaration
test.finalizedBy(foo)
```

This way, `foo` will run even if `test` has failed, similar to a Java `finally` block.

Comment: It's worthy to mention that the finalizedBy method is still marked as incubating.

Comment: Running into case where this isn't 100% accurate.