# Is there a method in Gradle to execute some task after the build?

Tags: gradle

Is there any method for executing some task after the build is done?

I have checked `doLast` but it is only for tasks (`task1.doLast(task2)`) and not for build...

Comment: You can't do `task1.doLast(task2)`.

Comment: So is there a way to execute `build.doLast(Task)` ? I know it should be a closure but maybe there is a way...

Comment: No there isn't. Options are to use task relationships such as `dependsOn` or `finalizedBy`, or a `gradle.buildFinished {}` hook.

Answer (score 12):

After reading and checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973365/gradle-execute-task-after-test-phase-even-if-test-has-failed) the answer is `build.finalizedBy(copyToLib)`

Comment: This will only work when `gradle build` is invoked. To make this work reliably, you either have to do `tasks.all*.finalizedBy(copyToLib)`, or use a hook such as `gradle.buildFinished {}` instead of a task.

Comment: I have also got to an issue that when i have submodules to build and in the submodule build script i would use `build.finalizedBy(copyToLib)`, the `copyToLib` task will be executed after whole main-project build is done. I would like to execute a simple "copy-to" task after a submodule is built. Is there any way?

Comment: Subprojects aren't built one after another. Task execution order is solely determined by task dependencies.

Comment: So could You propose some resolution to my problem? I have master project with 2 subprojects. In the end of "core" project i would like to copy some files into one particular folder ("libs"), so that second subproject could do sth with that folder (copy or use as dependencies).

Comment: Make the task in the second subproject that does something with the folder depend on the task in core that copies files to the folder. Or better, use a project dependency instead (see the "multi-project builds" chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html)).

Comment: PS: This is the problem you should have described in your question.

Answer (score 5):

You can call

```java
tasks.build.doLast(){
      println 'This will be printed after the build task even if something else calls the build task'  
}
```

Comment: Can anyone comment - is this different, better, worse than doing `gradle.buildFinished` as suggested above?