# Why android gradle task is starting before libs are built?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to fire up a task to copy the aar files (android libs) to a separate folder, but the task keeps getting triggered before the build starts.

I am using this answer but it does not work for me:

[Is there a method in Gradle to execute some task after the build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867318/is-there-a-method-in-gradle-to-execute-some-task-after-the-build)

Here's my gradle:

```
def buildLibrary = true;

if (buildLibrary) {
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
} else {
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs' //this way we can find the .aar file in libs folder
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        if (!buildLibrary) {
            applicationId "myapp.com.mysdk"
        }
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Support libraries and widgets
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'
}


// Why this keeps getting called before the build starts????

task copyAARToCommonLibs(type: Copy) {
    println 'calling copyAARToCommonLibs before libs are built!!!'
    from('../build/outputs/aar') {
        include '*-release.arr'
    }
    into '../MyOutput/libs'
    println 'end of calling!!!'
}

build.finalizedBy(copyAARToCommonLibs)

// This did not work either
tasks.build.doLast(){
    println 'This is never called!!!'
}
```

and the output from a clean build:

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Crashlytics was applied to an android-library project. 
Android-library support is currently an incubating feature. 
Contact support@fabric.io with any issues.
calling copyAARToCommonLibs before libs are built!!!
end of calling!!!
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
... a bunch of stuff
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 13.157 secs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print statements that you added to `copyAARToCommonLibs` are misleading you. Based on their position in the task definition they are being executed at configuration time independently of any inter-task dependency order. This is why the prints appear before the build process occurs (as the configuration is not dependent on the task dependencies).

Here is a simple example:

```
task blahTask() {
    println "Configuring finalizer"

    doLast {
        println "Actually running finalizer"
    }
}

task toFinalize() {
    println "Configuring to finalize"

    doLast {
        println "Actually running thing to finalize"
    }
}

toFinalize.finalizedBy(blahTask)
```

When I execute `toFinalize` the output is:

```
Configuring finalizer
Configuring to finalize
:app:toFinalize
Actually running thing to finalize
:app:blahTask
Actually running finalizer

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

As you can see the finalizer's configuration code is actually executed *before* the configuration code for the task to be finalized (i.e. independent of task dependencies) whereas the `doLast` code is running in the desired order.

As such, using the print statements in the way you have is not actually giving an indication of when the copy task is running.

Another thing to realize is that in your output (from what you showed) there are no `:app:copyAARToCommonLibs` statements indicating that the task is not actually being run (it is being configured, hence the prints). According to the [task docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html) a finalizer task will not run if the task being finalized (in your case `build`) was up to date. Quote:

> On the other hand, finalizer tasks are not executed if the finalized task didn't do any work, for example if it is considered up to date or if a dependent task fails.

Comment: understood and thx for the detailed explanation. Yet, I have aar files generated into the build directory but those never get copied. Can you spot why? thx.