# Gradle: How to upload release APK file over FTP after build

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to upload automatically the APK file to the server when building the release version.

To do so, I'm going to use FTP protocol.

I'm new regarding Gradle scripting. I used those 2 questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23867375/2145504) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054752/how-to-upload-folder-contents-to-ftp-server-using-gradle)) as a base but something is not working out.

Could anyone point out what it is?

This is the code (on build.gradle):

```
gradle.buildFinished {
println("---- Build finished. This message appears ----")
task ftp << {
    project.logger.lifecycle('-- This message does not appear --')
    ant {
        taskdef(name: 'ftp',
                classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.net.FTP',
                classpath: configurations.ftpAntTask.asPath)
        def destination = "ftp://xxxxxxxxxx@xxx.surftown.com/xxxxx/"
        def source = null
        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            if ( (variant.name).equals("release") ) {
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    source = output.outputFile
                }
            }
        }
        def user = 'xxxxxxxxx'
        def pass = 'xxxxxxxxx'
        ftp(server: source, userid: user, password: pass, remoteDir: destination)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`gradle.buildFinished` registers a hook executed at the end of the build. In your case it just creates the `ftp` task.

Use this if the `build` task is involved :

```
build.finalizedBy(ftp)
```

Otherwise, to make sure it works whatever the invoked task :

```
tasks.all*.finalizedBy(ftp)
```

By the way, it was explained in the comment section of first answer of your first link.